# How to create future with timeout and listeners

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, asynchronous, meteor

I am trying to create a function with a future. In this function, it will wait for an `End` or `Error` event. If no data is written for x seconds, it will return an error. Here is what I have written.

```
Cylon.execute = function (subroutine, timeout=60000) {
  let future = new Future();
  let done = future.resolver();

  let timeoutId = Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
    done(new Meteor.Error('CylonTimeout'));
  });
  this._messages.on('data', () => {
    timeoutId = Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
      done(new Meteor.Error('CylonTimeout'));
    });
  });
  this.on('End', () => {
    Meteor.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    done(null, subroutine);
  })
  this.on('Error', (err) => {
    Meteor.clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    done(err, null)
  });
  this._commands.write(`Execute #${subroutine}\r`, 'utf8');
  return future.wait();
}
```

I'm running across a few problems.

- When the future returns, the event listeners are still bound
- The future can return multiple times because of the timeout

How is this usually handled with futures? Is there some way to clean up these events?

Answer (score 2):

First I suggest you do this.once and not this.on so you will trigger the event handler only once.
There is no need to trigger it more than once.

Also I suggest you do

```
var self = this;
done = function (err, result) {
  //remove all listeners
  self.removeListener('Error', handler);
  //.... and so on....

  future.resolver()(err, result);//call actual done
}
```

That would prevent the done from being called more than once and remove the event listeners.

Comment: once will prevent multiple handling of same event, but you will still get multiple calls if different events are triggered, therefore you must also do the event listeners cleanup as I originally wrote.

Comment: The only other problem I am having is handling the timeout. I can't find anything in the fibers API that specifies "return only one future from a series of futures" (whichever returns first)

Comment: I think the issue is that you have multiple setTimeout there, So even when you cancel one, the other is still alive. So you must cleanup any setTimeout before creating a new one. You have 1 setTimeout at the start, but than on first on('data') you do another setTimeout and loose the first timeoutID and you didn't cancel that timeout. So.... you have it triggered although you don't really want to.